# If condition for VBScript on LDAP results

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ldap

I'm connecting with LDAP to Active Directory for a corporate phonebook. I'm grabbing the data I want, but I need to do an If...Else statement on some of the data I'm grabbing.

I want to check if the value in AD attribute 'homePhone' begins with "01". If it does, I want to write out its value. If it begins with anything else, I want to either write "" or "Not Valid".

Here's what I've been writing, but isn't working:

```
Response.Write "<td>"
if objRS("homePhone") = "01*"  then
Response.Write objRS("homePhone")
else
Response.Write ""
end if
Response.Write "</td>"
```

This seems to just go to the Else condition, and the homePhone attribute doesn't get written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards in string comparisons and, unfortunately, VBScript doesn't support the `Like` operator used in VBA/VB. You *can* use a regular expression but that's overkill for what you need here. Just strip the first two characters and perform your comparison.

```
If Left(objRS("homePhone"), 2) = "01" Then
```

If you need to perform case-insensitive string comparisons (not necessary in this situation, but may be helpful in the future), you can convert both strings to upper/lowercase before comparing or use the `StrComp()` function with the `vbTextCompare` parameter value.

```
If StrComp(Left(objRS("homePhone"), 2), "01", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
```

Comment: Very interesting, Mr Bond! Thank you very much for such a concise and clear answer. And quick, too. :)